# Creating a Signature Line

Tags: formatting

I would like to create a signature line shown in the picture. Could you please help me? [image]

Comment: If you hand in the paper in person, simply tell the people where to sign.

Comment: If you really need a line, use something like \rule{8cm}{.4pt}.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately I have used a table and I hope that I have helped you, also.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5in}p{4in}@{}}
Approved: & \hrulefill \\
& Fats Domino, Ph.D. \\
& Chair of the Department of Nutrition\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

A bit artificial, but doesn't need even knowledge about tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Approved: \hrulefill

\hspace*{0mm}\phantom{Approved: }Fats Domino, Ph.D.

\hspace*{0mm}\phantom{Approved: }Chair of the Department of Nutrition

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Six different approaches in no particular order here.

In each case is used a different way of obtain the underline rule and also the left indentation and hanging of the signature.

Note that I avoid intentionally the `\hrulefill` command since the rule is placed in the baseline, but it look better a bit below (to allow handwriting aligned vertically with "Approved:"), so four of the six  outputs are like this one:

> [image: mwe1]

Maybe also look better also a pointed/dashed line than a solid line, like `\dotfill`, but unfortunately (in this case) puts the points too high and scattered, so one approach use a custom `\dotsign`ature rule:

> [image: mwe3]

... and other a `\dashsign`ature rule:

> [image: mwe2]

Compilable code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\parindent0pt
\parskip3ex
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabto,ulem,booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\TabPositions{.38\linewidth,.5\linewidth}
\def\dotsign{\xleaders\hbox to .2em{\d{}}\hfill\d{}}
\def\dashsign{\xleaders\hbox to .5em{\_}\hfill\_}
\def\dummytext{\bigskip\dotfill and this text is the very 
inconclusive end of the very long report.\par~\par}

\begin{document}

\dummytext

\makebox[.5\linewidth][r]{Approved: }\dotsign\smallskip\\
\hspace*{.5\linewidth}Fats  Domino, Ph.D.\\
\hspace*{.5\linewidth}Chair of the Department of Nutrition

\dummytext

\tab\hfil Approved:\vspace{2pt}\tab\dashsign\\
\tab\tab\tab Fats Domino, Ph.D.
\tab\tab\tab Chair of the Department of Nutrition

\dummytext

\hfill 
Approved: \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{.4pt}\par\smallskip  
Fats Domino, Ph.D.\par
Chair of the Department of Nutrition}

\dummytext

{\parindent.38\linewidth\hangindent.5\linewidth\hangafter1
Approved: \uline{\hfill}\\[3pt]
Fats Domino, Ph.D.\\
Chair of the Department of Nutrition\par}

\dummytext

\tabcolsep0pt
\hfill\begin{tabular}{lp{.5\linewidth}@{}}
Approved:~ & \\[-3pt]\cmidrule{2-2} 
& Fats Domino, Ph.D.\\
& Chair of the Department of Nutrition\\
\end{tabular}

\dummytext

\hspace{.38\linewidth}Approved: \vbox to 0pt{\uline{\hspace{.5\linewidth}}\\[3pt]
Fats Domino, Ph.D.\\
Chair of the Department of Nutrition}%
\vspace{3\baselineskip}% only  you type something below

\end{document}
```

Disclaimer of responsibility: I am too lazy to set lengths with the  LaTeX syntax (i.e., I have used `\parindent0pt` instead of 
`\setlenght{\parinden}{0pt}` and so). I shall not be liable if this burn your brain, your computer explode or something catastrophic happens if you adopt my bad habits.

Comment: Your answer is pretty nice! But it would be nice to have a little bit more of an explanation to all these different approaches.

Comment: Of the six alternatives presented here, only the third and fifth survive these three requirements: signature line is solid; prompts besides "Approved" work; multiple sets of signature lines are still aligned.