# Adding a signature to a document

Tags: letters, signatures

I'm wondering, if it's possible to add a digital signature, as well as a physical signature (from a picture/scan of your actual signature) to a document in LaTeX? Or is the only way to accomplish this is adding the signature to the generated PDF?

Comment: My answer can be help for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368227/creating-a-signature-line/368256#368256

Comment: Adding the scanned signature is trivial with `\includegraphics`, for the digital signature see maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30382/192421

Comment: @Sebastiano no, I don't need to create a signature line.

Comment: @Richard Sorry for my misunderstood your request.