# Extend tabular signature lines to a prior parbox width automatically

Tags: parbox, signatures

My universities thesis style requirements dictate that a declaration page is furnished with information boxes (signature etc.). I can extend the signature lines to the end of the `\parbox` boundary manually (the `8.595cm`) but I am assuming that there is an automatic way to achieve this, I may need to change the font size in the future and hence the `parbox` width so it looks alright. A minimal example (modified from the [answer of Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368227/creating-a-signature-line#368256)):

```
% Extend signature lines to the length of the parbox automatically 
\documentclass[%12pt,
            oneside]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter*{\centering Declaration}

\begin{centering}

\parbox{10.5cm}{I declare that this thesis has been composed solely by myself and, except where otherwise stated and clearly indicated, is based on my own work and research carried out in the School of [School Name] at [University Name] between [Month] [Year] and [Month] [Year]. \\[8pt]}

\parbox{10.5cm}{I declare that this thesis has not been nor will be used for admission to a degree conferred by any other university or institution and neither has it previously been used for admission to a degree conferred by [University Name]. \\[26pt]}

% Doing it manually by eye sight led to a length of 8.595cm
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.5cm}p{8.595cm}@{}}
    Signature: & \hspace{0.2cm}\hrulefill \vspace{0.9cm}\\
    Name: & \hspace{0.2cm}\hrulefill \vspace{0.9cm} \\
    Date: & \hspace{0.2cm}\hrulefill \vspace{0.9cm}
\end{tabular}

\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

I would like it to look like this automatically if possible, this was achieved manually but even then, the right hand side lines are not flush with the `\parbox` text.

[image: How I want it to look automatically]

`\textwidth` produced this abomination:

[image: \textwidth]

I tried to use different margin lengths [contained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize#16956) but none seemed to work, I am not sure if I need to put the table in a `\parbox` too or if there is a way to calculate extending the signature line so it is flush. Any help would be appreciated, I couldn't find anything in other answers to help with this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much to have cited me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `tabularx` (which is loaded by `memoir`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,
            oneside]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter*{\centering Declaration}

\begin{center}

\parbox{10.5cm}{I declare that this thesis has been composed solely by myself and, except where otherwise stated and clearly indicated, is based on my own work and research carried out in the School of [School Name] at [University Name] between [Month] [Year] and [Month] [Year]. \\[8pt]}

\parbox{10.5cm}{I declare that this thesis has not been nor will be used for admission to a degree conferred by any other university or institution and neither has it previously been used for admission to a degree conferred by [University Name]. \\[26pt]}

% Doing it manually by eye sight led to a length of 8.595cm
\begin{tabularx}{10.5cm}{@{} l @{\quad} X<{\rule{0pt}{9mm}} @{}}
    Signature:  &   \\  \cline{2-2}
    Name:       &   \\  \cline{2-2}
    Date:       &   \\  \cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note: `centering˙ is not an environment but switch, i,e, should be used as` \centering`(after it all is centered), Instead of it I use`center` environment

Comment: That is perfect and what I wanted, thank you. I didn't know the difference between center and centering and will look into it in more detail as I have used it elsewhere in my document, is it usually center is the appropriate one or is it dependent upon context?

Comment: `\centering` is usually used in floats (`figure˙, `table`O or environments, in which you like to have centered content. In contrary to `center` environment, it not insert additional vertical space as environment `center` do.